# Should I release a Class object declared as property and retained in implementation?

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management

I am a bit confused whether I should release an object that I had declared as 'retain' in my interface and then in my implementation's init method retain it to avoid getting the object destroyed.

*Interface: LoginManager.h*

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) LoginViewController *loginView;
```

*Implementation: LoginManager.m*

```
- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [loginView initDetails];
        [loginView retain];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have this as an ARC project and made **'LoginManager'** as non ARC just to retain loginView.

If I don't retain **loginView** my object is already gone even when I'd retained it in the interface file, so I retained it explicitly in the **'init'** but where should I release it?

Should I autorelease it and then release it in my dealloc as it gives double free error sometimes and i suspect it is because of this LoginManager class:

```
loginView = [[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];

...

-(void)dealloc{
   [loginView release];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why did you disable ARC?

Comment: I didn't disable ARC but just excluded LoginManager from the ARC

Comment: Yes, but why did you do that?

Comment: If i didn't the object was destroyed before it was used. So to forcefully retain it I did this as you can't retain in an ARC project

Comment: Which object exactly? You will be better off getting help with that instead of this.

Comment: loginView is destroyed

Comment: Then you have worse problems than memory management with your code. Post all relevant code in a new question along with your problem.

Comment: If you do not `@synthesize` the property yourself, ivar for corresponding property would be `_loginView` and not `loginView` as you are using it. May be that is the bug.

Comment: I did synthesize loginView

Comment: okay in that case, you should take Jim's advice and locate the issue/post another question.

Comment: @Amar Starting from Xcode 4.4, you don't need to synthesize properties unless you want an ivar with a name other than `_nameOfProperty`.

Comment: @duci9y Yes, that is what I was telling OP in earlier comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going about this all the wrong way.  You had a bug in your code.  ARC wasn't the cause - ARC is reliable.  You don't have to disable ARC to "forcefully retain" the object, you need to track down the real bug.  If you don't do this, it is likely the original bug still exists waiting to ruin your day further down the line.  This is a nightmare for debugging purposes.

Re-enable ARC and fix the first bug.  If you can't track down the problem, post another question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Goodness me! You mean ARC wasn't the cause behind loginView getting destroyed? Could you provide some more light on possible causes.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that now

Comment: Alright after a deeper look at my code I have finally found out my exact bug and thanks Jim and @duci9y for pointing me towards the actual cause. I nailed it finally :) It was a problem with my singleton class and a case where i accidentally used dispatch main queue block. Thanks!!

Comment: As rightly suggested there indeed was no need to make it non ARC

Answer (score 1):

> I have this as an ARC project and made 'LoginManager' as non ARC just
>   to retain loginView.

Even in ARC you the view is retained if you use `strong`.

---

I assume you wish to use non-ARC, then you are doing wrong:

```
-(void)dealloc{
   [loginView release];
}
```

Here you need to call `[super dealloc]` as well.

Moreover: Please read memory management, whenever you `retain, copy, alloc` you need to send equal number of `release`.

So in your case "You need to release it."

Comment: sorry my bad. I did wrote super in my actual code. So you mean I should do away with explicitly retaining it in the init by just using strong in the interface?

Comment: @AtifImran: Yes, I think `strong` object will not allow the view to get released.

Answer (score 0):

It sound weird that your view is "gone" without ARC.
After alloc, you should have a retaincount of 1 for your iVar (then it should not disappear with the next `autoreleasepool`)

Note that you are not using the setter of your `retain property`, to use it you have to write :

```
self.loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

But in this case you will have a retain count of 2 (just like your manual call to `retain`)

I think that there is another mistake somewhere in your code ;) !